# MySQL limit by count and return items with same date

Tags: mysql, sql

Assuming I have the following table structure

```
CREATE TABLE `calendar` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `date` DATE NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

And the following data

```
INSERT INTO `calendar` (`title`, `date`)
VALUES ('Day 1 - Event 1', '2013-05-01'),
('Day 2 - Event 1', '2013-05-02'),
('Day 2 - Event 2', '2013-05-02'),
('Day 3 - Event 1', '2013-05-03');
```

I was hoping to limit the result set to 2 items but not cut the result in between items of the same date.

```
SELECT *
FROM `calendar`
WHERE `date` >= '2013-05-01'
LIMIT 2
```

Yield

```
('Day 1 - Event 1', '2013-05-01'),
('Day 2 - Event 1', '2013-05-02'),
('Day 2 - Event 2', '2013-05-02')
```

Instead of just

```
('Day 1 - Event 1', '2013-05-01'),
('Day 2 - Event 1', '2013-05-02')
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Can't you manage this with the server-side language of your choice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this should work putting your desired dates in a subquery:

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.* 
FROM `calendar` c
  JOIN (
       SELECT `date`
       FROM `calendar`
       WHERE `date` >= '2013-05-01'
       LIMIT 2
    ) c2 on c.`date` = c2.`date`
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5481e/1)

I would recommend adding an `ORDER BY` date to your query though as you can't guarantee the order of the results without.

Comment: You need `DISTINCT` in the subquery.

Comment: @ypercube -- That wasn't my understanding of the question.  Return 2 records, but don't cut off if other records exist with the same date.  If you include DISTINCT in the subquery, then it could easily return the incorrect records.  However, I do need DISTINCT in the main query :)

Comment: Sorry, I meant you need `DISTINCT` in the external query. See why: [SQL-Fiddle-2](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a1891/1)

Comment: @ypercube -- yep, updated the query and the fiddle -- thx for pointing it out!

Comment: @user1423172 -- np, glad we could help!

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want to show the first 2 items but if there is a tie (on the date) on the last item, to include tied results as well. SQL-Server has `TOP (2) WITH TIES` but unfortunately MySQL's `LIMIT` has no equivalent. So, the query has to be more complex:

```
SELECT *
FROM calendar
WHERE `date` >= '2013-05-01'
  AND `date` <= COALESCE(
       ( SELECT `date`
         FROM calendar
         WHERE `date` >= '2013-05-01'
         ORDER BY `date`
           LIMIT 1 
           OFFSET 1                          -- that's 2 minus 1
       ), '9999-12-31'  )
  ;
```

And another way, similar to @sgeddes's answer:

```
SELECT c.* 
FROM calendar c
  JOIN 
    ( SELECT DISTINCT `date`
      FROM
        ( SELECT `date`
          FROM `calendar`
          WHERE `date` >= '2013-05-01'
          ORDER BY `date`
            LIMIT 2
        ) AS c2
    ) AS cc 
      ON c.`date` = cc.`date` ;
```

Comment: +1 -- thanks again for pointing out DISTINCT!  Would not have thought about this approach.

Answer (score -1):

You can use DISTINCT clause.

```
SELECT DISTINCT(DATE),attrib2,attrib3,......
FROM `calendar`
WHERE `date` >= '2013-05-01'
LIMIT 2
```